# there is white pixels when i try to fill button with image

Tags: css

in `firefox` i can see a white pixels in the right/left bottom corners can i fix it ?

`firefox`

[image: firefox]

`chrome`

[image: chrome]

it not very big in chrome but i think there some white pixels also

i know you can barely see it but it's so annoying

i also tried to use the `background-image` but it didn't help
even if i use `overflow-hidden` it didn't help but
i can't use it any way because a have a blur shadow in the background of the button

```css
  body {
      background: #111;
  }

  button {
    border: none;
    background: #ddd;
    outline: transparent;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    transition: 0.3s;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    position: fixed;
    left: 10px;
    top: 10px;
    z-index: 999;
    display: flex;
  }
  
  button img {
    background: inherit;
    border-radius: inherit;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  button::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgb(var(--secound-1), 0.7), rgb(var(--primer), 0.7) 43%, transparent 0%);
    filter: blur(3px);
    z-index: -10;
    border-radius: inherit;
  }
```

```html
    <button class="start-button">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/rTEtbTg.png">
    </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `background` in `button`:

```css
body {
  background: #111;
}

button {
  border: none;
  background: none;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  z-index: 999;
  display: flex;
}

button img {
  border-radius: inherit;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<button class="start-button">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/rTEtbTg.png">
</button>
```

Comment: sorry it's my problem but the image is a png with no background i will upload it with out the background so test it after i remove the background